# Connect a C# Windows Form App to a MySQL Database on a Linux based server

Tags: c#, php, mysql, linux

I am working on an C# application which would use the remote MySQL database located in my website hosted on a Linux server with PHP & MySQL support.

I tried to connect directly to the MySQL database using **MySql.Data.MySQLClient** Reference, as a result, my program is throwing following exception :

"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

I searched many tutorials but got no solutions... getting the same error.

Can anybody please tell me how to do this.

Please suggest any online links or tutorials or your own idea.

Please help me.

here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace mysq
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {              
                string conn = "Server = myserver;database = db ;uid = username ;password = pwd ;";

                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conn);
                con.Open();
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from table", con);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    ad.Fill(dt);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                }

           }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I've written an own class with functions for my mysql-connection.

**First of all declare the server connection:**

```
string ServerConnection = "Server=localhost;Port=1234;Database=YourDb;Uid=user;password=pass;"
```

**This is how I select data:**

```
public static void DB_Select(string s, params List<string>[] lists)
        {
            try
            {
                using(var conn = new MySqlConnection(ServerConnection))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    string command = s;
                    cmd.CommandText = command;
                    using(var sqlreader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    while (sqlreader.Read())
                    {
                        if (sqlreader[0].ToString().Length > 0)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < lists.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                lists[i].Add(sqlreader[i].ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (List<string> save in lists)
                            {
                                save.Add("/");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error while selecting data from database!\nDetails: " + ex);
            }
        }
```

**The call:**

```
List<string> allRows = new List<string>();

DB_Select("SELECT field1 FROM table1 WHERE 1", allRows);
```

**Notice:** For every field you are selecting, you have to pass an own list which will be filled with the output.

---

For updating your database it would be quite the same function. You just wouldnt have to grad the output. Could look like this:

```
public static void DB_Update(string s)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ServerConnection))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    string command = s;
                    cmd.CommandText = command;
                    int numRowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    if(numRowsUpdated < 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Warning DB-Contact: Affected_rows < 0!");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Updating database failed!\n\nSQL: {0}\n\nERROR: {1}",s,ex.Message));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide proper connection string in your program, i am suspecious you are passing proper IP address or hostname of the server where you hosted the database. As a first step try to ping the db server to make sure it is reachable from your machine. If it is reachable try as follows:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
string myConnectionString;
string conn = "Server =<provide proper ip address >;database = db ;uid = username ;password = pwd ;";

conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString;
conn.Open();
```

More details here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html

Comment: I've copied and pasted the hostname and other details provided by web host , getting same error

Comment: Can you able to ping the host name successfully?

Comment: No cannot ping

Request Timed Out

Comment: Then how you can connect? Find an accessible ip address or hostname

Comment: I'm using a free domain and unfortunately they do not allow access to my sql remotely, I think this is the reason..

Thanks for your support :)